# Is it possible to disable the autoopen function of the angular ui datepicker?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I don't like the autoopen function of the angular ui datepicker  (the automatic display of the calendar when the control gets focus). What I want is to click a button to open the datepicker when needed, but otherwise leave the calendar closed. Is this possible with the angular ui datepicker? I didn't see any option in the documentation.

Comment: Here http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ , it is called only on click

Comment: Hi Prasath, I know how to respond to the click event to open the datepicker. What I want is to have the datepicker initially be closed when the control gets focus.

Comment: If i understand your comment, then i think you have to see the pop up section of the datepicker

Comment: I did read the pop up section. It doesn't seem to have a property to control the behaviour I am after.

Comment: Isn't that behavior exhibited [**here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/IaNYi6h6K3NM4dyMoTjz?p=preview) (sourced from the documentation)?

Comment: @Marc. You're right. That's the behaviour I'm after. But for some strange reason, it doesn't work in my app. Even stranger, I have discovered, it works when adding an empty datepicker-options directive to the input tag (the calendar is initially closed then). When removing the date-picker-options directive, the calendar is opened on focus. Have   to investigate this a bit more.

Comment: Interesting. If you get stumped, I'd be happy to take a look at a Plunker which demonstrates the issue if you would go through the trouble of making one. An added benefit which you may know is that setting one up sometimes helps to reveal the problem with your own code.

Comment: @Marc. Thanks, you're so right. I started the plunker work and then comparing your plunker and mine, I saw a different ui-bootstrap-tpls- version. Mine was ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js and yours was ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js. I changed your code to my version and it doesn't work. See your modified plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/OYYaJ42J397CZj5VMB5r?p=preview

Comment: Do you need to use the 0.10.0 release?

Comment: No, I have switched to the 0.11.0 version and everything works as advertised. Thanks again for making me write the plunker.